# Unit testing API endpoints that needs access tokens

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, access-token

I am trying to write a unit tests suite to test all end points of an API. But some of my API end points are protected and need access tokens. I understand that unit tests shall be independent and all prerequisites shall be mocked, but how can I mock an `access_token`?

I am using `Node JS` with `Sails JS` for backend development and `Mocha` framework for testing along with `Chai` assertion library. I am also using `jwt auth`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, how do you validate the access token?  Can't you also mock that?

Comment: I am using a function in the jwt package called verify. I don't really understand how can I mock that?

Comment: ...by moving those calls to another class with an interface, and providing a mock implementation for your unit tests.

Comment: Sorry for asking too much, but would it be a good practice if I issued a token inside the test using a mock user data?

Comment: For unit testing?  It depends exactly what you're testing.  If you're not testing the verify function itself, it may also be acceptable to use another mock verify function that does something much simpler (e.g. always returns success for a hard-coded test token)

Comment: Okay, I will consider that. Thanks.

Comment: If the library you're using is open source, there may already be a solution in the library's own unit tests, sometimes worth a look.